# Tomcat starts but shows blank on browser

Tags: java, tomcat

I have configured a tomcat application.

This is my server.xml.

When I start the tomcat it gives :

```
Dec 08, 2015 1:50:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'maxSpareThreads' to '50' did not find a matching property.
Dec 08, 2015 1:50:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'maxSpareThreads' to '50' did not find a matching property.
Dec 08, 2015 1:50:40 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Realm'.
Dec 08, 2015 1:50:40 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Host'.
Dec 08, 2015 1:50:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8491"]
Dec 08, 2015 1:50:40 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Dec 08, 2015 1:50:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8492"]
Dec 08, 2015 1:50:40 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Dec 08, 2015 1:50:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1482 ms
Dec 08, 2015 1:50:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Nightfire-webapps
Dec 08, 2015 1:50:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.24
Dec 08, 2015 1:50:41 PM org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener findDefaultHost
WARNING: Unknown default host [localhost] for service [StandardService[Nightfire-webapps]]
Dec 08, 2015 1:50:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8491"]
Dec 08, 2015 1:50:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8492"]
Dec 08, 2015 1:50:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 173 ms
```

But The browser shows blank page

Comment: Can you provide more info about your Tomcat version, OS, algorithm of installing (manually or automated)?

Comment: what do you type on the browser? if you use the default Tomcat settings, you can try `http://localhost:8080` . That should at least display the Tomcat default page